# Not receiving Dynamic Link when app is installed from the appstore

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

Not receiving dynamic link when app installs from the app store, In android works well this scenario. In ios it works when the app kills and clicks the link, but not work when installing from the appstore and opening the app.I am using react native firbase
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase
the same issue is found here
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/7160

Does anyone have an idea